# Choose and set billing city BEFORE checkout page in woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to create an option for non logged in users to Choose billing city in the home page and set the selected option of the user as the billing city in checkout page automatically.

Also when I set the dataType in ajax to 'json' I'm getting an error ( "parsererror" "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0) and without it I'm getting success, but when I get to the checkout page the city input is empty..

ajax-choose-city-script.js :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var select = $('#theCity'),
        value = select.val();

    function ajax_update( value ){
        $.ajax({
            url: ajax_city_object.ajax_url,
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: '',
            data: {
                action: 'ajaxCitySelect',
                value: value
            },
            success: function (respond) {
                console.log(respond);
                console.log('success'+ value);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
                            console.log('error'+ value);

            }
        });
    }

    ajax_update( value );

    $('body').on('change', select, function () {
        value = select.val();
        ajax_update( value );
    });
});
```

functions.php :

```
if(is_front_page() && ! is_user_logged_in()){
add_action('init', 'ajax_Choose_city_init');
}

function ajax_Choose_city_init(){

    wp_register_script('ajax-Choose-city-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-choose-city-script.js', array('jquery') ); 
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-Choose-city-script');
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-Choose-city-script', 'ajax_city_object', array( 
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'redirecturl' => home_url(),
    ));
    
    // Enable the user with no privileges to run ajax_login() in AJAX
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajaxCitySelect', 'ajax_Choose_the_city' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxCitySelect', 'ajax_Choose_the_city' );
}

function ajax_Choose_the_city(){
$info = $_POST['value'];
if(isset($info)){
$customer = new WC_Customer();
$customer->set_billing_city($info);
$customer->set_shipping_city($info);
  echo json_encode( $info );
    die();
}
}
```

html in home page :

```
<label for="cities">Choose Your City:</label>

<select name="cities" id="theCity">
  <option value="New-York">New York</option>
  <option value="Los-Angeles">Los Angeles</option>
  <option value="Chicago">Chicago</option>
</select>
```

Obviously It is not working :/